# Why use Prepard Statements/mysql_real_escape_string for SQL queries

Tags: php, mysql

I have read various articles suggesting to use `Prepared statements` in SQL queries, but since `mysql_ lib does not allow executing 2 queries in one statement` is it worth to use them if I need to fire a query only once in the execution of the page and it some cases the mysql_query also seems to ignore invalid post data (like `'ADMIN' OR 1--`)

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=$username AND password=$password");

//processing
```

Now, If anyone passes "username" as

```
'ADMIN' OR 1--
```

The above query dosent fetch the "Admin" row! Is this a feature of mysql_query that ignores the comment after `'1' / Special chars`. How would a SQL Injection happen in this case, running MYSQL 5.5 and PHP 5.3

Comment: This query will simply break on the unquoted strings (`password` in this case).

Comment: http://ferruh.mavituna.com/sql-injection-cheatsheet-oku/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `'ADMIN' OR 1--` doesn't work, but `'ADMIN' OR 'x' = 'y'` certainly would, since it would result in this SQL query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM users
 WHERE username = 'ADMIN'                    -- true
    OR 'x' = 'y' AND password = 'whatever'   -- false, but who cares?
;
```

The general lesson: coding for security is hard, because we're not used to thinking in terms of hostile agents actively seeking to disrupt our code. SQL injection is a solved problem, and the solution is parameterized queries, so you should use that rather than trying to roll your own attempted solution.

Comment: if we are using `mysql_real_escape_string()`.than should we need to use `mysqli`

Comment: If you're diligent about using `mysql_real_escape_string()` then you're safe. The problem is that we're human and sometimes forget (I know I have). Prepared statements can't make this mistake.

Comment: @Barmar: That's true, but the title of the question was "Why use Prepard Statements/mysql_real_escape_string for SQL queries", so I don't think the OP was asking about why we should use prepared statements *instead of* `mysql_real_escape_string`.

Comment: "Prepared statements can't make this mistake."  This is false:  $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$user'") has the same SQL injection vulnerability as a non-prepared statement.  The point I'm trying to make is that we can't just go around saying "use this and nothing will go wrong" because if they don't understand the proper use or the reason why blindly throwing user generated data into a query is bad, they will still be open to making mistakes.

Comment: @ruakh I was addressing jhonraymos's comment, not the original question.

Comment: @bobwienholt Calling that "using prepared statements" seems to be just playing semantic games. To be strictly true, I should have said "if you only use placeholders to insert variables". But my main point was that forgetting to use mysql_real_escape_string is an easy mistake to make when you're doing variable substitution, but if you're in the habit of using prepared statements you're less likely "accidentally" do normal substitution.